# Static map to function pointers

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement something similar to C# setters in C++. The idea is to have an enum of class properties and the corresponding setters. My code looks as follows. I will write the implementation in the class definition.

```
#include <string>
#include <map>

enum ClassProperties
{
    Id, Name
};

class MyClass
{
public:
    int Id;
    std::string Name;

    public void SetValue(ClassProperties c, std::string value){
            setters[c](this, value);

   }

private:
    typedef void (* t_setter)(MyClass *, std::string);

    static void set_id(MyClass * obj, std::string value) {
         obj->Id = std::stoi(value);
    }
    static void set_name(MyClass * obj, std::string value) {
         obj->Name = value;
    }

    static std::map<ClassProperties, t_setter> setters = {{ClassProperties:: Id, set_id}, {ClassProperties::Name, set_name}};


};
```

I'd expect this code to choose the cooresponding function and call it, but I get an error on the last line

```
error: in-class initialization of static data member ‘std::map<ClassProperties, void (**)(MyClass*, std::basic_string<char>)> MyClass::setters’ of incomplete type

error: could not convert ‘{{Id, MyClass::set_id}, {Name, MyClass::set_name}}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘std::map<ClassProperties, void (**)(MyClass*, std::basic_string<char>)>’
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: clang++ gives a more direct "error: non-const static data member must be initialized out of line"

Comment: Once you have got this working, you might want to look into "pointers to member functions", so you can make `set_id` and `set_name` be non-static functions and can be called as `obj.set_id(value);`

Comment: BTW. This doesn't look anything like C# setters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initialization of `setters` is wrong. You should change it as follows:

1) Remove the line from the class body:

```
static std::map<ClassProperties, t_setter> setters =
    {{ClassProperties:: Id, set_id}, {ClassProperties::Name, set_name}};
```

2) Add appropriate initialization of static member out of the class body:

```
std::map<ClassProperties, MyClass::t_setter> MyClass::setters = {
        { ClassProperties::Id, &MyClass::set_id },
        { ClassProperties::Name, &MyClass::set_name }
};
```

Besides, you have to remove *public* specifier before `SetValue` function.

[**wandbox example**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5mhF3Rprxo4kLlHH)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but now I get 
 `multiple definition of `MyClass::setters'`

Comment: @Vahagn I have added a wandbox example.